# directory says it is group writable but I cannot write a file within it

Tags: permissions

I have a group called `service` in `/etc/group` that has user `webserver` as a member.

I am trying to write to a file in `/home/service` using user `webserver`. I have a script that confirms that user `webserver` has write permission to `/home/service`, yet when I want to write to `/home/service/entries_for_processing`, then I get a permission denied error, even though both `/home/service`, and `/home/service/entries_for_processing` are writable by group `service`.

What don't I understand about group permissions that it denies me permission to write to `/home/service/entries_for_processing` as a member of `service` group?  Below are the permissions of `/home/service` and `/home/service/entries_for_processing`:

```
# file: home/service/entries_for_processing
# owner: service
# group: service
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---

# file: home/service/
# owner: service
# group: service
user::rwx
group::-w-
other::---
```

By the way, the script I mentioned that confirms that user `webserver` can write to `/home/service`, also strangely confirms that `webserver` cannot write to `/home/service/entries_for_processing` nor to any other file I try to open or create in `/home/service`.

Comment: You don't have execute permissions, so you can't 
traverse the directory and accesss the internal directory or any other contents.

Comment: Since the group does not have `x` permissions on the directory, it lacks permissions to access files therein.